# Make scheduled call on Azure with webjobs

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-webjobs

I have a nodejs application deployed on Azure and I want to make a call to it let's say every friday.

Can I upload a .bat file to the webjob and tell it to call app.azurewebsites.net/test ?

Is it possible this way or is it more complex than this?

Thank you,

Mihai Dobrescu

Comment: If you just want to call the website from azure webjobs, it's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

If you just want to call the website from webjobs, it's possible. Otherwise, you can ignore my answer.

I'm not familiar with .bat, here is an link [Azure WebJob calling a Web Page using Powershell](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jpsanders/2017/05/12/how-to-azure-webjob-calling-a-web-page-using-powershell/). You can modify to .bat in the same way.

---

Please correct me if I misunderstand you.

If you just want to call the site url deployed in azure every Friday, you can just write some code to call the website(.bat / powershell / .net etc.) as webjobs, then set the schedule as per the [Cron Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer#cron-expressions)(the site is broken now, please refer to this [one](https://codehollow.com/2017/02/azure-functions-time-trigger-cron-cheat-sheet/)).

If call every Friday at 9:00, the schedule like below:

```
0 0 9 * * Fri
```

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to Azure WebJobs, it is actually a background app. It is not supposed to accept an incoming request just like that. However, it makes sense to post some data to a Azure queue/table record and have the WebJob or anything else read it to take suitable action. If you explain in more detail, I can help more.

Not to complicate stuff, but Azure functions also help a lot in scenarios like these.